# Unique local solution to ODE $\dot{u}=f(u).$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fixed-point-theorems, lipschitz-functions

Prove that for any $u_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n,$ there exist $T=T(|u_0|)>0$ and a unique $u \in C([0,T])$ solving $$u(t)=u_0+\int_0^tf(u(s))ds,$$ for all $t \in [0,T].$ Assume that $f$ is locally Lipchitz. Recall that $C([0,T])$ is the Banach space with the norm sup $||u||:=\sup_{s \in [0,T]}|u(s)|.$

This is my proof:

Since f is locally Lipschitz, for any $u_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n,$ there exist $\delta>0$ and $M>0$ such that $$\|f(u)-f(u_0)\| \leq M\|u-u_0\|\,\,,\forall u \in \bar{B}(u_0,\delta).$$
Since $u$ is continuous at $t=0$ then there exist $\delta_0$ such that $$\|u(t)-u(0)\|\leq \delta\,\,,\forall |t| < \delta_0.$$
Let $T <\min\{\delta_0; \dfrac{1}{M}\}$ then we get $$\|u(t)-u_0\|\,\,\,,\forall t \in [0,T].$$
Define $T(u)(t)=u_0+\int_0^tf(u(s))ds$ for all $u \in C([0,T])$ then $T(u) \in C([0,T]).$ Now, I prove $T$ is contractive. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
||T(u)-T(v)||&=\sup_{t \in [0,T]}|T(u(t))-T(v(t))|\\
& =\sup_{t \in [0,T]}\left|\int_0^tf(u(s))-f(v(s))ds\right|\\
& \leq \sup_{t \in [0,T]}\int_0^t\left|f(u(s))-f(v(s))\right|ds\\
& \leq \sup_{t \in [0,T]}M\int_0^t\left|u(s)-v(s)\right|ds\\
& \leq \sup_{t \in [0,T]}M \|u-v\|t\\
& \leq MT \|u-v\|.
\end{align*}
Since $MT <1,$ by the Banach's fixed point, there exists a unique $u \in C([0,T])$ such that $u = T(u)$, which completes the proof.

I wonder my proof is correct? This is because compare to the proof of Picard–Lindelöf theorem, I do not define the mapping T on the space $X:=\{u \in C([0,T] \,\,\,|\,\,\, \|-u_0\| \leq \delta\}$ but using the continuity of $u$.

Comment: To use the fact that $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous you need $u,v \in \overline{B}(u_0,\delta)$, so you want to define your operator $T$ on the space $X$.

Comment: Your proof assumed gthat $M$ was a global Lipschitz constant.

Comment: I think since $\forall s \in [0,T],$ by the continuity of $u$ at $s=0$ we have $u(s), v(s) \in \bar{B}(u_0,\delta).$ This means we can use the condition locally Lipschitz at $u_0$ without defining X.

Comment: The purpose of choosing $T < \delta_0$ to ensure that $\forall t \in [0, T],$ we always have $u(t) \in \bar{B}(u_0,\delta)$ and we can apply local Lipschitz condition.